# onMouseUp and onKeyUp are returning different elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On a parent element I am trying to handle the mouse and keyboard events. **onMouseUp** event is returning a child element which triggered the event while **onKeyUp** is returning a parent element.

Here's my code:

```
<div className={s.editorDesc} tabIndex="1" contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning="true" ref={(input) => {
              this.editorDesc = input;
            }} onMouseUp={(e) => {
              console.log(e.target);
                // this.showControls(e);
            }} onKeyUp={(e) => {
              if (e.key === "ArrowRight" || e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
                console.log(e.target);
                // this.showControls(e);
              }
            }}>
            {this.state.controls}
            <div>
              <p>Description of Article</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**onMouseUp** is logging ***p*** while ***onKeyUp*** is logging **div**. I want to know the reason behind this behavior and also how can I access child element which triggered the event in case of **onKeyUp** event.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div tabIndex="1" contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning="true" ref={(input) => {
              this.editorDesc = input;
            }} onMouseUp={(e) => {
              console.log(e.target);
                // this.showControls(e);
            }} onKeyUp={(e) => {
              if (e.key === "ArrowRight" || e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
                console.log(e.target);
                // this.showControls(e);
              }
            }}>

            <div>
              <p>Description of Article</p>
            </div>
          </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: can you post a working fiddle or something?

Comment: attached the fiddle.

Comment: Consistency with `contentEditable="true"`? hehe

Comment: onMouseUp triggers p cause your mouse is located on top of the p directly .. but since onKeyUp is a keyboard input e.target will trigger div since the event is initiated to the div.. as for the alternative to get the p child, you can use jQuery's $( event.target ).children('p')... hope this helps

Comment: I want the access the child which triggered the event not specific p all the time.

Comment: The issue is that the inner `p` is not the thing that is editable and has keyboard focus, that's the outer `div` so I believe you will always get keyboard events against the `div`. It's been awhile since I used `contentEditable` but I'm pretty sure you can figure out where the current selection is in the DOM, that's probably your best bet.

Comment: To achieve this you need an event attached to the p elements .. to watch for p elements in the div like jQuery does with .on ex. $('div').on('click', 'p', function.. again that's not the case here since you use contentEditables

Comment: To be honest I can see the logic behind keyboard events firing on editable elements only. Couldn't you give the `<p>` an `id` attribute or something?

Comment: Thing is I want to access the child element which trigger the event not specially the <p> . Since its editable more children could be added. In case of click its doing fine.

Comment: @BilalSaeed Fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: @Ant's Updated please try now.

Comment: @BilalSaeed "I want to access the child element which trigger the event" In what sense do you think the `<p>` triggered the event? With mouse events it makes sense, because you click at a particular position on the screen, which contains a particular HTML element. But why are keyboard events attached to particular HTML elements? It sort of makes sense to attach it to whichever element is in focus, but that wouldn't be the `<p>` in this case.